# Cannot execute systemd service running as a non privileged user on CentOS 8

Tags: permissions, centos, systemd, selinux

There is (maybe) a change between CentOS 7 and 8 in regard of systemd and selinux I yet do not know how to deal with this.

For some reason (cross distribution compat) we are using postgresql 9.6 from [EnterpriseDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). The installer work fine on CentOS 7 **but no longer on CentOS 8**. The installer creates a systemd service running as user postgres (uid=1004 in my case).

```
[Service]
Type=forking
TimeoutSec=120

User=postgres
Group=postgres
...
```

At the end of the installer the service is started using systemctl. This fails now on CentOS 8. When I do a systemctl status I see this:

```
postgresql.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
```

In the filesystem and regarding user the permissions everything is perfectly fine.

**As soon as I disable SELinux it starts working!**

This was not needed on CentOS 7. Can anyone tell me what I can do now AHEAD of calling the installer to make its execution working?

**Addendum**

I maybe found the real reason for the problem. I am installing to a different disk and not the root file system. The installer starts to work if I install onto the root filesystem. **As soon as the executable where the "ExecStart" directive from the systemd service file is on another disk it is no longer working.** How to tell the system to allow this???

Thank you very much for enlighting myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem a week ago.
It did not mention that before in my question as I thought that would not matter.

I was installing to a fresh and empty seperate disk. Not the root filesystem. I found out that installing on the root filesystem worked.

I than did a

```
restorecon -r /mountpoint-of-new-disk
```

and after that it started to work!

I believe doing this was not needed for CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

A different disk as in a different part of the file hierarchy ?

With SElinux in force that forces you to understand selinux and how to create file context translations !
Try what happens if you change for example ntpd's config file and ntp's log files to somewhere else like: /services/ntpd/ntp.conf and /services/ntpd/ntp.log !

Comment: thanks for the idea. But I found out that it had to do that I installed on a seperate disk. See my answer above for details.

Answer (score 0):

You copied the hierarchy from root (/) and downwards to a currently mounted disk (ie mounted as /tmp/tmp_mnt) ?

The restorecon -r resets context on files... so ls -Z is your friend

ls -Z on the systemd unit files for postgres and the postgres binary is interesting.

It is probable that the SElinux policy differs between centos7 and centos8.